# Windows Azure Scheduled Web Jobs "Failed to retrieve schedule information for subscription"

Tags: azure

I'm trying to set up a scheduled 'web job' in Windows azure and I get this error message:

Failed to retrieve schedule information for subscription '99c5eb1b-a0d0-4b8f-b16e-bc5cd2610f6c'.

I have subscribed to the 'Windows Azure Scheduler' preview on http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/preview/

'On demand' jobs work very well.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I tried the occurrence job with my subscription without any errors. Since this is a preview feature I'd suggest you contact MS support. It might be something wrong in azure. But please double check the job was created under the subscription you applied for this preview especially if you have multiple subscription under the same LiveID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted MS Azure support and this was a bug in the Azure portal which has now been fixed.